# Glyphicon shows above the button text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, button, glyphicons

The Glyph-icon shows above the Button Text. I tried using     `vertical-align: middle;` But it does not work still.

**Code :**

```
<li>
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="buttonuser" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" style="font-size: 30px; vertical-align: middle;"></span>
            <?php
                if (isset($_SESSION['vorname'], $_SESSION['nachname'])) {
                    echo "<p>" . $_SESSION['vorname'] . " " . $_SESSION['nachname'] . "</p>";
                } 
            ?>
    </button>
</li>
```

[image: This is an image of how it looks.]

Comment: Looks like there’s not enough space for both the Icon and the text, did you try `white-space: nowrap;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `display` CSS attribute for the `p` tag is block. Try using a `span` instead. If the text still shows up below the icon, try changing the button `width` or setting the `display` CSS property of the icon to `inline-block`.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <li>
<button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="buttonuser" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <?php
            if (isset($_SESSION['vorname'], $_SESSION['nachname'])) {
                echo "<p>" . $_SESSION['vorname'] . " " . $_SESSION['nachname'] . "</p>";
            } 
        ?>  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" style="font-size: 30px; vertical-align: middle;"></span>
</button></li
```

Your HTML should be like this. This will work fine and you will not have to do anything else.